# UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator isn't showing

Tags: ios, uitableview

Scenario: Using custom cell UITableViewCell XIB (without any storyboard).

Also: set accessor type within the NIB.  - I tried both within NIB & via Code.

Attempting to set the cell-accessor type:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Result: No accessory type shown.

Why?

The cell only has two (2) labels with plenty of space available for the AccessoryView.
Here's the cell code:

```
@interface MyStoreTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *storeDistanceLabel;
@end
```

Here's the body:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyStoreTableViewCell *cell = (MyStoreTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

Address *address = _storeAddresses[indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.storeAddressButtons[indexPath.row]];

cell.addressLabel.attributedText = [NSAttributedString staplesNormalAttributeStringOf:[address toString] havingFont:[UIFont staplesLightMediumFont]];

NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.1f miles",[address.distance floatValue]];

cell.storeDistanceLabel.attributedText = [NSAttributedString staplesNormalAttributeStringOf:myString havingFont:[UIFont staplesLightMediumFont]];

// ...this doesn't have any effect:
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Are you loading Tableview from Storyboard? If yes, then please check whether your "ProtoType" cell has accessoryType set?

Comment: No...I'm loading it from an XIB.

Comment: Could you show the code where you create your custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView  registerClass:[MyStoreTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UserTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I changed the 'registerNib' to 'registerClass' per your suggestion.  That was worse: no cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are missing to add customcell nib file. Please find the below which may help you.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";    
    DeficiencyTableViewCell *cell = (DeficiencyTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray * topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DeficiencyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell = (DeficiencyTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cell.mFacilityLbl_.text = @"Fac";
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```